# Bootstrap tooltip is not visible using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am new to Bootstrap. I am using bootstrap range slider and javascript in my program. Inspite of using following, I am not able to see tooltip of slider:

```
<input id = "cheapHFSlider" type="range" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" 
                data-slider-tooltip="show" onchange="sliderChanged(this)">
<label id = "cheapHFSliderVal">
```

When I hover my cursor over that slider in Chrome's debugging mode, I can see that 'tooltip tooltip-main top' is being highlighted in Elements tab of debugger. Attaching the screen shot of above.[image: Please refer the 1st slider. The class in selected div in Elements tab is highlighted. I could not take screen shot at the perfect time. Please ignore other 3 sliders on web page.]

Related CSS and JS are:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap slider CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.1/css/bootstrap-slider.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap slider JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.1/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
```

My script tag is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#cheapHFSlider").slider().on('slide', function(_event) {
                $("#cheapHFSliderVal").html(_event.value + "%");
            });
            $("#cheapHFSliderVal").html($("#cheapHFSlider").slider('getValue') + "%"); // set the initial value of slider in label
        })

        function sliderChanged(slider) {
            switch(slider.id) {
                case 'cheapHFSlider':
                    $("#cheapHFSliderVal").html(slider.value + "%");
                    break;

                default:
                    console.log("Invalid slider '" + slider.id + "' !");
            }
        }

</script>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - your code does not run even after I add jQuery UI and bootstrap: https://jsfiddle.net/su7ek282/

Comment: Added the missing tags of CSS and JS.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/anujap/13ndyju4/12/